# How can I use numerical labels for regression in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I search the Caffe source code a bit, and the `ReadImageToDatum` function in `caffe/src/caffe/util/io.cpp` only supports `int` type labels.

I've also noticed that there's an `array_to_datum` function in `caffe/python/caffe/io.py`, which seems to not have the constraint on the type of label, but I'm not exactly sure how I'm supposed to use it.

How can I use numerical (non-integers) labels for regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `Datum` type was designed with image classification in mind.
For regression, I recommend using `"HDF5Data"` input layer.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) for example.

Using hdf5 binary files allows for more flexibility in the number, shape and type of inputs you feed your net.

Comment: thank you much for answering, would you have any thoughts on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38432568/3041068)?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472977/1714410), caffe's `Datum` class only support `int` type labels.
In `caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto` it is defined

```
message Datum {
  optional int32 channels = 1;
  optional int32 height = 2;
  optional int32 width = 3;
  // the actual image data, in bytes
  optional bytes data = 4;
  optional int32 label = 5;
  // Optionally, the datum could also hold float data.
  repeated float float_data = 6;
  // If true data contains an encoded image that need to be decoded
  optional bool encoded = 7 [default = false];
}
```

So in the generated `caffe.pb.h` file it's like

```
private:
  ...
  ::google::protobuf::int32 channels_;
  ::google::protobuf::int32 height_;
  ::std::string* data_;
  ::google::protobuf::int32 width_;
  ::google::protobuf::int32 label_;
  ::google::protobuf::RepeatedField< float > float_data_;
  bool encoded_;
  ...
```